# Building business marketplace for local business using Magento

Tags: magento2

I'm new to Magento. I learnt about features of Magento2. I'm planning to develop business marketplace for local businesses where any business(Groceries) can register. After register business could create stores(multiple location). Each store could have online store as well as offline POS. Each store would have it's own `Inventory`, `Catalog`, `Vendor`, `Shipping`, `Payment`, and so on.

Can anyone suggest me how should I start processing? Any extensions that can be implement for above business model? This might be vague question. :)